# Не могу настроить маску для TextBox jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$("#TextBoxSomeID").mask("1..1000..10000");
```

Нужно, чтобы в поле можно было вводить цифры от 1 до 10000

Comment: Не смотрите на кавычки, использую C# ASP.NET, другие кавычки он не распознает, проверял, другие JQ функции работают, ну и сам код пишу в блок document.ready

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще для таких вещей я бы использовал плагин для валидации, маска конкретно тут не совсем подходит, пользователь сразу получает информацию о некорректном вводе и не имеет простой возможности отправить кривые данные.

С одинарными кавычками в ASP.NET проблем быть не должно, ты пишешь свои скрипты в отдельном файле с расширением .js?

```js
$('#test_form').validate({
  lang: 'ru',
  rules: {
    maskedText: {
      required: true,
      max: 10000,
      min: 0
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.17.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.17.0/localization/messages_ru.min.js"></script>
<form id="test_form">
  <input type="text" id="maskedText" name="maskedText" />
</form>
```

Comment: Спасибо, такой вариант подходит тоже, уже допилю часть так как мне нужно. О плагине валидации не знал до этого =D

Comment: Ну и проблем нет с кавычками, файл скрипта у меня в студии и она принимает для ввода двойные кавычки и при компиляции всё делает "правильно" для браузера. Я уточнил о них для преждевременных ответов про неправильные кавычки.